# Rails duplicate the first record

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a simple index.html.erb which shows current orders row by row. It has paths **Show**, **Delete** and **Duplicate**

I just want to duplicate a single record. When I click on duplicate, It duplicates the first record in the database regardless of the row I clicked.

I tried almost every suggestions on site. Finally I decided ask you.

My method in **controller**:

```
  def duplicate
    @order = Order.find_by(params[:id]).dup
    @order.save

    redirect_to root_path
  end
```

My **index.html.erb**

```
  <tr>
    <% @orders.each do |order| %>
      <td><%= order.customer.name %></td>
      <td><%= link_to order.ref.upcase, order %></td>
      <td><%= order.ebat %></td>
      <td><%= order.adet %></td>
      <td><%= number_to_currency(order.price) %></td>
      <td><%= number_to_currency(order.price * order.adet, precision: 0) %></td>
      <td><%= order.created_at.strftime("%Y-%m-%d") %></td>
      <td><%= order.urun.upcase %></td>
      <td><%= order.termin.strftime("%Y-%m-%d") %></td>
        <td><%= link_to "Bu siparişi sil", order_path(order), data: {
                          turbo_method: :delete,
                          turbo_confirm: "Eminsin ?"
                        } %> | <%= link_to 'Duplicate', duplicate_order_path %>

  
      </p>
    </tr>


# I tried by indicating base_id as well but the result is the same 
# <%= link_to 'Duplicate', duplicate_order_path, base_id: order.id  %>
```

So If you can help me I would be really grateful.

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Add parameter to path:

```
duplicate_order_path(id: order.id)
```

And change

```
Order.find_by(params[:id]).dup
```

To

```
Order.find(params[:id]).dup
```

Or

```
Order.find_by(id: params[:id]).dup
```

Comment: Man you're my savior
`duplicate_order_path(id: order.id)` and 
`Order.find_by(id: params[:id]).dup` worked perfectly!! Thank you so much!